# Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 CSS Changes

Tags: css, joomla

I recently updated a Joomla website from 1.5 to 2.5.  The theme on 1.5 was a customized version of the Beez template.  I converted the template to 2.5, and have everything working except the main content blocks, which look like the CSS isn't there for them.

The site is http://www.nocbor.com

The main article (*Welcome to NOCBOR*) used to be in its own separate box, and the articles used to be side by side.

Is this caused by upgrading the template and possible breaking the CSS?  Or is there something I need to change in the admin panel from 1.5 to 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

The default layouts for Joomla 2.5 are different from 1.5, just inspect the html in your browser and you will find some differences up the tree i.e. a missing div or a div named "item" which became an ... just take those differences into account and update your css accordingly.